# XML Entities Not Loading in Any Browser simplexml_load_string()

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, entity, dtd

```
<?php
$x="<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>";
$x.="<!DOCTYPE xmlfile [<!ENTITY test SYSTEM 'file:///D:/x.txt' >]>";
$x.="<xmlfile><data>&test;</data></xmlfile>";
$xml=simplexml_load_string($x);
echo "<pre><h1>" . "OUTPUT:" .  $xml->data;
?>
```

It Shows Blank Output :( But it Works on My Mate's PC .... Help! Please Thnx in Advance :) 
I Have Tried Both my Windows and Linux BoX !! Doesn't work for me

-> a Newbie

Comment: `ENTITY test SYSTEM 'file:///D:/x.txt'` your server has access to this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it with

```
$xml=simplexml_load_string($x, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOENT);
```

The third paraemter is explained at http://docs.php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php

```
LIBXML_NOENT (integer)
  Substitute entities
```

Comment: Thnx Bro!! @VolkerK Worked ^_^